# Oracle conditional statements

Tags: oracle, condition

I am making a report, and I am trying to do following:
If the value of the field is NULL, output empty string. Another words, I don't need the word "null" to be output to the user, just empty string. Is that possible to write such a SQL query? How? 
I don't even know how to formulate a google search request for this case, so I am sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Search string: "oracle replace null with [whatever you feel like]"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the NVL function for this.

> NVL(columnName,'')

will substitute an empty string for a null value in columnName.

Comment: Right you are. Edited as such.

Comment: There is practically no difference in Oracle between the empty string and the `NULL` value. How does this suggestion answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, empty string `''` when assigned to a varchar2 type is NULL for all intents and purposes. In my SQLdeveloper, on a 12c database, the following query results in a *`(null)`* for every column. If you display to user a blank (a space, `' '`) it would surely be displayed by all tools as a blank.

```
SELECT NULL, '', CAST('' as varchar2(1)), CAST('' as char(1)), NVL(null,'') FROM dual;
```

[Why Oracle violates the SQL92 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)